# UIActivityIndicatorView Not Appearing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityindicatorview

I am trying to show a UIActivityIndicatorView while my table view is loading data and have it disappear once loading is finished. The loading indicator never appears. What am I doing wrong?

```
#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
#define storeURL [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=25&playlistId=PL9DC706DCCCE00188&key=AIzaSyBS4do208_KPGHAhszfVkHadSvtfSgr7Mo"]

#import "BBYoutubeVideosTableViewController.h"
#import "Reachability.h"
#import "TSMessage.h"
#import "TSMessageView.h"
#import "YoutubeCell.h"
#import "KFBYoutubeVideoView.h"
#import "KFBAppDelegate.h"

    @interface BBYoutubeVideosTableViewController ()
    {
        UIActivityIndicatorView *loadingIndicator;
    }

    @end

    @implementation BBYoutubeVideosTableViewController
    @synthesize title, videoID, thumbURL, descriptionString, url, titleArray, videoIDArray, thumbArray, descriptionArray;

    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
    {
        self = [super initWithStyle:style];
        if (self) {

        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];

        UIImageView *backgroundImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"plain_app-background.png"]];

        CGFloat width = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width;
        CGFloat height = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height;

        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
        {
            loadingIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(width / 2, height / 2, 37, 37)];
            loadingIndicator.center = CGPointMake(width / 2, height / 2 - 37);
        }
        else
        {
            loadingIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(142, 365, 37, 37)];
        }

        loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray;
        loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;

        Reachability *networkReachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
        NetworkStatus networkStatus = [networkReachability currentReachabilityStatus];

        if(networkStatus == NotReachable)
        {
            [TSMessage showNotificationWithTitle:@"Network Error" subtitle:@"No active network connection!" type:TSMessageNotificationTypeError];

            [loadingIndicator stopAnimating];
        }
        else {
            [self.tableView addSubview:loadingIndicator];
            [loadingIndicator startAnimating];
        }

        self.title = @"Bluegrass & Backroads";

        self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
        self.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundImage;

        url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=25&playlistId=PL9DC706DCCCE00188&key=AIzaSyBS4do208_KPGHAhszfVkHadSvtfSgr7Mo"];

        dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
            if (data == nil)
            {
                NSLog(@"data is nil");
            }
            else
            {
                [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
            }
        });
    }

    - (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [loadingIndicator stopAnimating];
    }

    - (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData
    {
        NSError *error;
        titleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        videoIDArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        thumbArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        descriptionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        NSArray *items = [json objectForKey:@"items"];

        for (NSDictionary *item in items)
        {
            NSDictionary *snippet = [item objectForKey:@"snippet"];
            title = [snippet objectForKey:@"title"];
            videoID = [[snippet objectForKey:@"resourceId"] objectForKey:@"videoId"];
            thumbURL = [[[snippet objectForKey:@"thumbnails"] objectForKey:@"default"] objectForKey:@"url"];
            descriptionString = [snippet objectForKey:@"description"];

            [titleArray addObject:title];
            [videoIDArray addObject:videoID];
            UIImage *thumbnailImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:thumbURL]]];
            [thumbArray addObject:thumbnailImage];
            [descriptionArray addObject:descriptionString];
        }

        [self.tableView reloadData];

        [loadingIndicator stopAnimating];
    }

    - (IBAction)morePressed:(id)sender
    {
        NSURL *kyfbVideos = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL9DC706DCCCE00188"];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:kyfbVideos];
    }

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return [titleArray count];
    }

    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        return 215;
    }

    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return 60;
    }

    - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        UIColor *kfbBlue = [UIColor colorWithRed:8.0/255.0f green:77.0/255.0f blue:139.0/255.0f alpha:1];

        UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.frame.size.height)];
        footerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        CGFloat width = footerView.frame.size.width;

        UIButton *moreButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        moreButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [moreButton setTitle:@"More" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [moreButton setTitleColor:kfbBlue forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        moreButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        moreButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FranklinGothicStd-ExtraCond" size:25.0];
        moreButton.frame = CGRectMake(width / 2 - 25, 0, 50, 50);
        moreButton.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0;
        moreButton.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
        moreButton.layer.borderColor = kfbBlue.CGColor;
        moreButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
        moreButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [moreButton addTarget:self action:@selector(morePressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [footerView addSubview:moreButton];
        return footerView;
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UIColor *kfbBlue = [UIColor colorWithRed:8.0/255.0f green:77.0/255.0f blue:139.0/255.0f alpha:1];

        YoutubeCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"youtubeCell"];
        if (!cell)
        {
            NSArray *nibs =[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YoutubeCell" owner:self options:NULL];
            cell = [nibs firstObject];
        }
        cell.videoTitle.text = [titleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.videoDescription.text = [descriptionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.videoThumbnail.image = [thumbArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.videoTitle.textColor = kfbBlue;
        cell.videoDescription.textColor = kfbBlue;
        cell.videoTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FranklinGothicStd-ExtraCond" size:22.0];
        cell.videoDescription.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FranklinGothicStd-ExtraCond" size:16.0];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        return cell;
    }

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
        {
            KFBYoutubeVideoView *videoView = [[KFBYoutubeVideoView alloc]init];
            videoView.videoIDString = [videoIDArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            videoView.videoTitle = [titleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            videoView.videoDescription = [descriptionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:videoView animated:YES];
        }
        else
        {
            KFBYoutubeVideoView *videoView = [[KFBYoutubeVideoView alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
            videoView.videoIDString = [videoIDArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            videoView.videoTitle = [titleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            videoView.videoDescription = [descriptionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            NSMutableArray *details = [self.splitViewController.viewControllers mutableCopy];

            UINavigationController *detailNav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:videoView];

            [details replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:detailNav];

            KFBAppDelegate *appDelegate = (KFBAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
            appDelegate.splitViewController.viewControllers = details;
            appDelegate.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
            appDelegate.splitViewController.delegate = videoView;
            [appDelegate.splitViewController viewWillAppear:YES];
        }

        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @end
```

Comment: FYI - why do you create, setup, and start the loading indicator and then check the network status? Check the status first. Only show the loading indicator if you actually need it.

Comment: That was an oversight.

Comment: set delegate loadingIndicator.delegate = self;

Comment: @ZAZ, You don't set a delegate for UIActivityIndicatorView

Comment: you are adding it as child of uitableview, instead add it as child of self.view, and ensure it zindex level

Comment: @ZAZ, I have tried adding it as a subview of self.view and that did not work either.

Comment: is it enabled and user interaction also enabled

Comment: Is what enabled? The loading indicator?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. tableView was being initialized after adding loadingIndicator as a subview.